# schema methods doesn't work with find method in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I created a `schema.methods.toAuthJSON` which will return filtered data.
while i use `findOne()` it works just fine. but When I use just `find()` it doesn't work. how should i get it right?

```
Member.findOne().exec((err, member) => {

res.json(member.toAuthJSON())
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question definitely needs more detail but *IF* we assume as stated that the shown `findOne` code works but the not shown `find` code does not, then it is probably due to the return value not being used correctly for the `find` code.

#### Assumption for missing `find` code:

```js
Member.find().exec((err, member) => {
  res.json(member.toAuthJSON())
});
```

Again, if this assumption is correct then it is a misunderstanding of the returned value from `find`. While `findOne` will return a single document, `find` returns an *array* of documents. So the assumed code would need to be updated to iterate over the returned array invoking the custom method for each document.

One approach would be to use a map:

```js
Member.find().exec((err, members) => {
  res.json(members.map((member) => member.toAuthJSON()));
});
```

This approach will map over the returned array of documents returning a new array of outputs from the custom method.

Comment: Your assumption is correct! and your approach is works just fine! Thanks!

Comment: @GolamRabbani I'm glad that I was able to help. :)